# JAVA - How to play audio sound represented as float[] or double[]

Tags: java, audio

I read an audio file in bytes, then i do FFT (as low-pass-filter) on the audio byte[], so the output of the FFT is a double[] (of Real and Imaginary).
Now i wanna play the result to hear the sound.
I use SourceDataLine if i will play a byte[].

So the problem, is how can i play the double[] ??

Thanks,

Samer Samy

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I realized that noone ever gave you a solution to your question.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best approach would be to convert it back to byte[].

You could do this using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and a `DataOutputStream`.

The `ByteArrayOutputStream` one allow retreive the content of the stream as a byte array and the `DataOutputStream` allow you to write double to the stream.

Comment: yeah, the DataOutputStream will allow me to write to a file, but it wont allow me to play it directly to the speakers ...

Comment: Actually I meant you could write to a ByteArrayOutputStream and then retrieve an array of bytes from it. Try wrapping the byte array output stream with a data output stream. Then if you keep a reference to the wrapped ByteArrayOutputStream you will be able to retrieve it as an array of bytes. Also note that the content of the ByteArrayOutputStream will be placed in virtual memory, not into a file.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @Lynch's answer, which apparently wasn't clear enough for the OP:

```
byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
dataStream = new DataOutputStream( byteStream );

// write each element of your double[] to dataStream

dataStream.close();
byteStream.close();

byte[] audioBytes = byteStream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Yes I mean exactly this. Sometimes its easier to understand with an example.